# Force Lowercase URL for Reverse Proxy on Ubuntu Apache Server

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, reverse-proxy

How can I rewrite a request that comes in so that it is all lowercase?  I've looked around and some answers were to use the rewrite Module but those weren't for the specific case of using a reverse proxy.

What I would want is for a request that comes in like this:

`http://mywebsite/SomeApPlIcAtIon`

to be converted to this:

`http://mywebsite/someapplication/`

Any Suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

I've got it setup with what I assume should be correct, my httpd.conf looks like this:

```
servername localhost
RewriteEngine on
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

My reverse proxy is setup in a file in conf.d called sabnzbd.conf as such:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /sabnzbd/ http://192.168.21.21:9999/sabnzbd/
ProxyPassReverse /sabnzbd http://192.168.21.21:9999/sabnzbd/
```

In my enabled-sites, my 000-defailt I have all `AllowOverride` set to `All`

When I go to 192.168.21.21/sabnzbd/ it works just fine.

When I go to 192.168.21.21/SABNZBD/ I get a 404. The rewrite rule doesn't work.

When I go to my rewrite log file to check it out, there is no data.

What is going wrong?

Comment: why the client does not send the correct url ?

Comment: see this answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/18740

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Apache server on Ubuntu - you can use mod_rewrite module.

You can follow this blog (URL: http://www.chrisabernethy.com/force-lower-case-urls-with-mod_rewrite/ ), it describes steps to configure the module.

Comment: What I'm not sure of, is where the ReWrite rule should go.  I am not currently using an .htaccess file.  Should it go in the httpd.conf?

Comment: Technically it will work either way - .htaccess file only applies to folder in which it is placed and sub folders. It is recommended to put rules in httpd.conf file. Unless required .htaccess file should not be used - it has got performance as well as security issues. You can refer to official documentation of Apache.